# Can I have multiple request in one form using php (laravel)

Tags: php, forms, laravel, request

I'm building a website in which the user can create articles with multiple images.

I would like to let the users while editing the form to can delete some image that they want. So I want to have in my form the main submit button that execute the function that store all details of article but also to I have another submit button that execute the function that delete the image.

How can I do that?

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: So you need to upload images while editing a form and if user dont like image he can delete it ?

Comment: yes, but also if the user wants to edit the article in the future to can delete some image.

Comment: Why you don't make view like edit-article/{id}, and that in that view do all edits, updates, inserts etc for that article only. Also you can use ajax to upload images and delete them without submiting a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you want 1 FORM, 2 SUBMIT buttons, and based on which one you press, do a different action? It is possible to do this, but not very practical.
To do it, create 2 submit buttons with each a value. I.e.:

```
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="delete image" />
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="send the form" />
```

when doing this, your post/get data will contain one item names mysubmit with the value, so you know which button was pressed, and you can do an action based on this.

However, when you submit a form by pressing a submit button, you do send the whole thing to your server, and have a page refresh. I usually prefer to use Ajax for the simple operation. For example, I would remove the delete submit button and replace it a simple button. When pressed, send an Ajax call to tell the server to delete the image, and use DOM to delete the image in the browser DOM tree (usually jQuery). Note that you can also use Ajax to post the form, nicer interface, and no page refresh.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try with Ajax